# Trapping all `a` clicks including ones added dynamcally

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I know you can bind to click events with jQuery like so:

```
$('a').click(function(){});
```

But what about html elements that are added dynamically? Lets say I have a `div` with the following contents:

```
<div>
    <a href='location.html'>location</a>
</div>
```

Now I call:

```
$('a').click(
      function(){ 
          console.log("going to " + $(this).attr('href')); 
          return true;
      });
```

And that will work fine. But if somewhere along the line I call

```
$('div').("<a href='location2.html'>location2</a>");
```

without explicitly binding that event handler to that event then the event handler will pick up on it.

Is it possible to rebind when ever a new `a` element is added. Or even better, when ever the `location.href` property is changing so I can add a get parameter to it every time.

For example if I was binding to a click event on an `a` element the event handler would be:

```
function(){
    var newid = parseInt(Obj.Request('pageid'), 10) + 1;
    location.href = $(this).attr('href') + '?pageid=' + newid.toString();
    return false;
}
```

Assuming the `Obj.Request` is a function that returns a get parameter. (I already have this in place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it in this manner:

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'a', function() {
      console.log("going to " + $(this).attr('href')); 
      return true;
});
```

---

Working on your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2CG2/4/) link.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the function `.on`.

Comment: Will this catch everything that matches it? No matter if it was added dynamically or static?

Comment: See... http://jsfiddle.net/L2CG2/ 

I want something that will make `2` raise an event. But not explicitly call `on` every time, more so have another event handler that grabs this and does it for me?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    //works on non dynamic elements present at page load
});

$('#some_non_dynamic_parent_ID').on('click', 'a', function() {
    //works on dynamic elements added later
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `.on()`, but as a delegation method.

Bind it to the closest static parent - for this example I'll just use `body`.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will wait until the event bubbles up to the `body` element and check what the original target of the event was - if it was an `a` element, it'll fire the handler.

Comment: Thats what I wanted :) How about capturing the location.href change?

Comment: Would `location.href` changing not cause a page reload and your javascript to be re-initialized?

Comment: Pretty much. I want to change one thing in it before it continues. But I guess this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Well you can use `onbeforeunload` if you really wanted to catch something happening before a user navigates from your page. But this will be fired when the user closes the window too, so make sure you handle this case.

Comment: How could I tell the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .on() or live() functions if you use jquery upper then 1.7 version. About the difference of these functions you can [read in this article](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/)